# running "mvn appfuse:gen" does nothing

Tags: java, maven, appfuse

I'm Using **Oracle db** alongside the **Appfuse** ,but it does nothing when using command above (**mvn appfuse:gen**).for example, it's expected to generate a *PersonDao/PersonDaoHibernate* class in the **dao** folder if we use the command . but nothing's happened. Meanwhile, I'v visited the following Pages:

http://static.appfuse.org/plugins/appfuse-maven-plugin/gen-model-mojo.html

http://static.appfuse.org/plugins/appfuse-maven-plugin

but couldn't *reconstruct* it's content in practice. Does anybody can show a tutorial that basically explain the details ,please (Say, from generating the pojos .. to jsp files)?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a JavaBean (POJO class), you could generate all layers with following command:

```
mvn appfuse:gen -Dentity=Name
```

where '**Name**' has to be replaced with Name of your JavaBean (Entity). Alternatively, you can use:

```
mvn appfuse:gen -Damp.genericCore=false -Dentity=Name
```

if you don't want to use GenericDao and GenericManager.

For further investigation I suggest: 
http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+Maven+Plugin#AppFuseMavenPlugin-amp-crud

Comment: what do you mean nothing? It's working, I'm using it frequently. If you create appropriate POJO class with all necessary annotations you can run that maven command (mvn appfuse:gen.....) and you'll get DAO, Service, webapp layers.