# Generating CRUD with Appfuse Maven Plugin(AMP)

Tags: maven, appfuse

A few Days Ago I Used the Command **mvn appfuse:gen** to generate CRUD with the Appfuse. But it Generated the folllowing files/classes for a given class (say, Category):

1) Category-validation.xml

2) CategoryAction-validation.xml

3) CategoryAction.java

4) CategoryActionTest.java

5) CategoryForm.jsp

6) CategoryList.jsp

I Expected it will generate the `CategoryDao/CategoryDaoHibernate` or maybe `CategoryManager/CategoryManagerImpl` Classes at least !!! But I was wrong.

Instead, we have the following code in CategoryAction class:

**private GenericManager categoryManager;**

And this is in Contradiction with the appfuse's standard tutorial ([See this Page](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+Maven+Plugin#AppFuseMavenPlugin-amp-crud))

**Can anybody tells me how to generate the CategoryDao/CategoryDaoHibernate and CategoryManager/CategoryManagerImpl Classes for the project?**

Answer (score 1):

Use -Damp.genericCore=false when you run appfuse:gen. Like the following:

```
mvn appfuse:gen -Dentity=Category -Damp.genericCore=false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already explained in following post:

[Stackoverflow: running “mvn appfuse:gen” does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221229/1622492)
but basically, it's the same like previous post from [Matt Raible](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65681/matt-raible)

After running that command (for EVERY entity), you'll get:

- **DAO layer**

  - DAO interfaces
  - DAO (Hibernate) implementation
- **Service layer**

  - Manager interfaces
  - Manager implementations
- **Webapp layer**

  - Controllers (if you are using SpringMVC framework)
  - JSP pages

and whole bunch of all other required resources (various Resource Bundle properties, Spring XML files, Menu configurations...). Of course, it's all *based on your model, your defined JavaBean classes*.

After that, you just need to put some extra code inside implementation  classes if you need some customized functionalities, some additional business logic.

I hope it helps.